# creating more than one label variable programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, label, concatenation

How can I create more than one label variable programmatically I tried following code but I am unable to create, is there any way to concatenate a variable name and a integer?

```
for(int intNum=0;intNum<3;intNum++)
{
    UILabel *lblText1;
    UILabel *lblmany = [lblText1 stringByAppendingString:intNum];   
    lblmany = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 50, 200, 30)];
    lblmany.text = strLable1Caption;
    lblmany.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;  

    [self.view addSubview:lblmany];
    [lblText1 release];
    [lblmany release];
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code doesn't make much sense

Comment: i am trying to create 3 labels with defferent properties & should be placed in different locations

Comment: I see that, but what do you expect to happen?

Comment: i need  to create 3 labels with defferent properties(size,text, etc..) & should be placed in different locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating label with same frame, how come it will be placed at different location ?? Define frame dynamically not with static values, And if you want to apply different properties use switch case if want to use for loop only ,else define separately and not in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ridiculous (and stringByAppendingString is an istance method of NSString calss so you cant access it with UILabel). what are you trying to do if you want to create number of labels the do some thing like this.

```
for(int intNum=0;intNum<3;intNum++)
{


    UILabel *lbl;

lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 50, 200, 30)];
lbl.text = strLable1Caption;
llbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;  


    [self.view addSubview:lbl];

    [lbl release];
lbl=nil;

}
```

Comment: i have tried this, but it will create 3 lables with identicle properties & one upon the other,, but i need to create 3 lable with defferent properties & should be placed in different locations

Comment: you need to change logic according to you, i am showing way which support you to make labels. You need to add some multipliers with i and set the x and y for locations and give different string what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**myController.h**

```
      #defune MAX_LABELS 2048
        @interface myController : UIViewController
        {
            UILabel                 *myLabels[MAX_LABELS];
            NSInteger               myLabelsCount;
    }
    - (void) createMyLabels;
    - (void) removeMyLabels;

    @end
```

**myController.m**

```
    @implementation myController

        - (void) createMyLabels
        {
            [self removeMyLabels];

            float x = 10.0;
            float y = 5.0;


           myLabelsCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < [No of labels]; i++)
            {

                  myLabels[myLabelsCount] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 200, 30)];
                  myLabels[myLabelsCount].text = strLable1Caption;
                  myLabels[myLabelsCount].textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;  


                   [self.view addSubview:myLabels[myLabelsCount]];
                   myLabelsCount++;
                   y = y + 15.0;
            }
        }

        - (void) removeMyLabels
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myLabelsCount; i++)
            {
                [jmyLabels[i] removeFromSuperview];
            }
            myLabelsCount = 0;
        }

        - (void)dealloc {

            [super dealloc];
        }


        @end
```

Comment: ya i tried but it is crashing at this line -------        myLabels[myLabelsCount] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 200, 30)];

Comment: I have edited the code. pls try again. Sorry for my silly mistake. Now try it.

Comment: actually i had corrected ur mistakes n tried but it was crashing,even now its crashing at same line

Comment: Can you check value of myLabelsCount? Make it 0 before for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to create buttons at different locations, you can use UILabels instead of buttons.

```
     int x =15;  
     int  y =12;   
     for (int i =0 ; i <numberamount; i++)   {  
        if (x>273) {   
            x=15;  
            y=y+50;  
        }  
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
        button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 40, 40);  
        [button setTitle:[nmb objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
        NSString *tagindex = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[nmb objectAtIndex:i]];  
        int tagindexint  = [tagindex intValue];  
        [button setTag:tagindexint];  
        [buttons addSubview:button];  
        [tagindex release];  
        x = x+75;  
    }
```